# Subquery aggregate function with SUM(CASE SUBQUERY)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, subquery, aggregate-functions

I'm getting an error while executing my query

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an
>   aggregate or a subquery.

Code:

```
SELECT 
    S.id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN sc.coverage IN (SELECT number FROM ArrayOfIntegersFromString(@dynamicData)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as sm
FROM 
    Storefronts s
    LEFT JOIN StorefrontCoverages sc ON s.id = sc.storefront
    LEFT JOIN Vendors v ON s.vendor = v.Id
WHERE
(
    v.active = 1
    AND
    s.approved = 1
    AND
    s.status = 1 
)
GROUP BY S.id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN sc.coverage IN (SELECT number FROM ArrayOfIntegersFromString(@dynamicData)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  > 0
ORDER BY sm desc
```

`SUM` in `SELECT` is not that important as the one in `HAVING`, so if someone can help me out even without that `SUM(...)` in `SELECT` it would be helpful.

Comment: Since T-SQL doesn't have arrays, that's a really badly named function you have there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be better to move the subquery to the `from` clause.  Based on your logic, you are looking for `join`s, not `left join`s -- after all, the `having` clause is simply looking for any match.

I think the following query does what you want:

```
SELECT S.id, COUNT(dd.number) as sm
FROM Storefronts s JOIN
     StorefrontCoverages sc
     ON s.id = sc.storefront JOIN
     (SELECT number FROM ArrayOfIntegersFromString(@dynamicData)
     ) dd(number)
     ON sc.coverage = dd.number
WHERE s.approved = 1 AND s.status = 1 AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Vendors v
              WHERE s.vendor = v.Id AND
                    v.active = 1
             )
GROUP BY S.id
ORDER BY sm desc;
```