# Using an Aggregate function with a sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

We get a new batch of widgets each month.  We know the product codes of these widgets which will be is stock, waiting to be used.  Each also has an availability date, after which it can be used.

> Table WidgetStock
>
> Columns: WidgetID, AvailabilityDate,

Another table has the uses of the widget, ie when it was first used.

> Table WidgetsUsed
>
> Columns: datetime, Operator

I'd like to see by day and hour the amount of fresh widgets that I have used for the first time, since the start of the month.  The widgets will be used multiple times, so a simple distinct count by hour is not really enough, as widgets would be double counted.

In my mind this would require looking at a list of available numbers, which is updated for each line of a group by query.

The below query will not work, but hopefully it shows what I am trying to achieve:

```
declare @StartofMonth datetime
set @StartofMonth = '20160901'

select CONVERT(varchar, wu.datetime, 103)'Date'
    , convert(char(2), wu.datetime, 108)'Hour'
    --Problem Line below
    , SUM(case when wu.StockNo in (select ba.NUMBER 
                                from widgetStock ba 
                                where availability_date between CONVERT(varchar, wu.datetime, 103) and @StartofMonth) then 1 else 0 end) 'Number Used'
from widgetsUsed wu
    left join widgetStock ws on wu.StockNo = ws.NUMBER
where wu.OPERATOR = 'WidgetWorld'
    and DATETIME between '20160914' and '20160916'
group by CONVERT(varchar,wu.datetime,103), convert(char(2), wu.datetime, 108)
```

Any help with this is appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sample data and desired results do wonders for explaining many problems.

Comment: @tompreston What error you are getting?

Comment: @JibinBalachandran "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery."

Comment: @tompreston  GordonLinoff had already answered it.Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30121392/subquery-aggregate-function-with-sumcase-subquery

Answer (score 0):

If understood your requirement then below script may solve your problem

```
declare @StartofMonth datetime
set @StartofMonth = '20160901'

select CONVERT(varchar, wu.datetime, 103)'Date'
   , convert(char(2), wu.datetime, 108)'Hour'
   , SUM(ISNULL(ba.NUMBER,0)) 'Number Used'
from widgetsUsed wu
left join widgetStock ws on wu.StockNo = ws.NUMBER 
LEFT JOIN widgetStock ba ON wu.StockNo = ba.NUMBER  AND availability_date between CONVERT(varchar, wu.datetime, 103) and @StartofMonth
where wu.OPERATOR = 'WidgetWorld' 
and DATETIME between '20160914' and '20160916'
group by CONVERT(varchar,wu.datetime,103), convert(char(2), wu.datetime, 108)
```